# nvidia-smi executable file not found on docker in WSL

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nvidia-docker

I set up CUDA on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 and am able to successfully run commands like:

```
docker run --gpus all nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample:nbody nbody -gpu -benchmark
```

and

```
docker run -it --gpus all -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter
```

but

```
docker run --gpus all --rm nvidia/cuda:10.0-runtime nvidia-smi
```

gives me this error and I do not have a good mental model of how docker works:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "nvidia-smi": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

This command works outside of docker.

```
nvidia-smi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether `nvidia-smi` works outside of Docker is irrelevant.  The error message is telling you that the image `nvidia/cuda:10.0-runtime` does not have `nvidia-smi` on the `$PATH`, which probably means it doesn't have it installed at all.  If the `nvidia-smi` executable is on the image but not on the `$PATH`, then you just need to provide the absolute path to the executable. If the executable is not on the image, then you need to use a different image which *does* have `nvidia-smi` on the `$PATH`, either by extending `nvidia/cuda:10.0-runtime` via a `Dockerfile` or by using a different image.

(Since `nvidia-smi` is really for development and sysadmin purposes, it doesn't surprise me that something labelled `runtime` is missing it.)